# javax.mail.MessagingException: Server doesn't support required transport level security

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail, thymeleaf

I am implementing mail service inside my spring mvc application. I am using `org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine` for mail.

I created a simple service `EmailService.java`

```
@Service
public class EmailService {

    private static final String EMAIL_TEXT_TEMPLATE_NAME = "text/email-text";
    private static final String EMAIL_SIMPLE_TEMPLATE_NAME = "html/email-simple";
    private static final String EMAIL_WITHATTACHMENT_TEMPLATE_NAME = "html/email-withattachment";
    private static final String EMAIL_INLINEIMAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME = "html/email-inlineimage";
    private static final String EMAIL_EDITABLE_TEMPLATE_CLASSPATH_RES = "classpath:mail/editablehtml/email-editable.html";

    private static final String BACKGROUND_IMAGE = "mail/editablehtml/images/background.png";
    private static final String LOGO_BACKGROUND_IMAGE = "mail/editablehtml/images/logo-background.png";
    private static final String THYMELEAF_BANNER_IMAGE = "mail/editablehtml/images/thymeleaf-banner.png";
    private static final String THYMELEAF_LOGO_IMAGE = "mail/editablehtml/images/thymeleaf-logo.png";

    private static final String PNG_MIME = "image/png";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine htmlTemplateEngine;

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine textTemplateEngine;

    @Autowired
    private TemplateEngine stringTemplateEngine;


    /*
    /* 
     * Send HTML mail (simple) 
     */
    public void sendSimpleMail(
            final String recipientName, final String recipientEmail, final Locale locale)
            throws MessagingException {

        // Prepare the evaluation context
        final Context ctx = new Context(locale);
        ctx.setVariable("name", recipientName);
        ctx.setVariable("subscriptionDate", new Date());
        ctx.setVariable("hobbies", Arrays.asList("Cinema", "Sports", "Music"));

        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        final MimeMessage mimeMessage = this.mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
        message.setSubject("Example HTML email (simple)");
        message.setFrom("thymeleaf@example.com");
        message.setTo(recipientEmail);

        // Create the HTML body using Thymeleaf
        final String htmlContent = this.htmlTemplateEngine.process(EMAIL_SIMPLE_TEMPLATE_NAME, ctx);
        message.setText(htmlContent, true /* isHtml */);

        // Send email
        this.mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
    }
}
```

and here is my `context.xml`

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!--<bean id="IMailService" class="sg.com.ctc.eportal.mail.service.impl.MailService"></bean>-->
    <bean id="EmailService" class="sg.com.ctc.eportal.mail.service.EmailService"></bean>

    <!-- SET default mail properties -->
    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="port" value="25"/>
        <property name="username" value="howtodoinjava@gmail.com"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- You can have some pre-configured messagess also which are ready to send -->
    <bean id="preConfiguredMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
        <property name="to" value="somebody@gmail.com"></property>
        <property name="from" value="howtodoinjava@gmail.com"></property>
        <property name="subject" value="FATAL - Application crash. Save your job !!"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="TemplateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="htmlTemplateResolver"/>
        <property name="templateEngineMessageSource" ref="emailMessageSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emailMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="mail.MailMessages"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="htmlTemplateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver">
        <property name="order" value="2"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/mail/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML"/>
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
        <property name="resolvablePatterns">
            <set>
                <value>html/*</value>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

When I call the email service from my junit test case  it is working fine and triggering email. But when I trigger the same via web application UI, I am getting below error

```
    2017-07-16 16:24:08 INFO  LeaseService:48 - Inside send mail service
DEBUG: getProvider() returning provider protocol=smtp; type=javax.mail.Provider$Type@110b4be2; class=org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport; vendor=Apache Software Foundation;version=1.0
smtp DEBUG: Attempting plain socket connection to server localhost:25
220 SGALX10000108.sgctc.corp ESMTP SubEthaSMTP null
EHLO SGALX10000108
250-SGALX10000108.sgctc.corp
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN
250 Ok
smtp DEBUG: Processing extension 8BITMIME
smtp DEBUG: Processing extension AUTH LOGIN
smtp DEBUG: Processing extension Ok
2017-07-16 16:24:08 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:851 - Initiating transaction rollback
2017-07-16 16:24:08 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:284 - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [ConnectionID:2466 ClientConnectionId: 502e91d5-cb7d-46d1-9d3e-320c2e7c53e7]
2017-07-16 16:24:08 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:327 - Releasing JDBC Connection [ConnectionID:2466 ClientConnectionId: 502e91d5-cb7d-46d1-9d3e-320c2e7c53e7] after transaction
2017-07-16 16:24:08 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2017-07-16 16:24:08 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:133 - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String sg.com.ctc.eportal.web.controller.LeaseController.createRequest(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap)]: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Server doesn't support required transport level security. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Server doesn't support required transport level security; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: javax.mail.MessagingException: Server doesn't support required transport level security
2017-07-16 16:24:08 DEBUG DefaultListableBeanFactory:251 - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorController'
2017-07-16 16:24:08 DEBUG ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver:361 - Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView sg.com.ctc.eportal.web.controller.ErrorController.exception(java.lang.Throwable)
2017-07-16 16:24:08 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:1197 - Handler execution resulted in exception - forwarding to resolved error view: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'error'; model is {errorMessage=Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Server doesn't support required transport level security. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Server doesn't support required transport level security}
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Server doesn't support required transport level security. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Server doesn't support required transport level security; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.MessagingException: Server doesn't support required transport level security
    at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.sendHandshake(SMTPConnection.java:811)
    at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPConnection.protocolConnect(SMTPConnection.java:149)
    at org.apache.geronimo.javamail.transport.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:165)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:251)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.connectTransport(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:501)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:421)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:345)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:340)
    at sg.com.ctc.eportal.mail.service.EmailService.sendSimpleMail(EmailService.java:130)
    at sg.com.ctc.eportal.core.service.impl.LeaseService.sendMail(LeaseService.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.sendMail(Unknown Source)
    at sg.com.ctc.eportal.web.controller.LeaseController.createRequest(LeaseController.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-07-16 16:24:08 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:992 - Could not complete request
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'error' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-07-16 16:24:08 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:105 - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

What configuration I am missing? Any suggestion.

Comment: Does your e-mail server support STARTTLS? That may be the problem.

Comment: You have enabled debug logging for JavaMail, please post the debug output as well.

Comment: @holmis83 using fakeSMTP server for development. But via junit test case it is properly sending.

Comment: It looks like your JUnit test uses a different configuration, that doesn't require starttls. Make sure your mail server on localhost supports starttls, or use an alternative config for testing locally.

Comment: I copied the same context from test case and used here.

Comment: I followed https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-springmail and it is working fine with the fakeSMTP server. In my application the additional config is spring security alone. Is there anything needs to be done there?

Comment: Based on the debug output, you might be using the old GNU JavaMail implementation instead of the official [JavaMail reference implementation](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).  Check your classpath and upgrade to the official version if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding not needed information to the properties of MailSender.

Gmail and your server don´t support SSL.

Here you got a code example that works

```
  Properties props = System.getProperties();
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
     protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
     }
  });

  try {

     Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

     msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("MAIL_FROM"));
     InternetAddress[] address = { new InternetAddress("MAIL_TO") };
     msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
     msg.setSubject(subject);
     msg.setSentDate(new Date());
     msg.setText(messageText);

     Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");

     transport.connect();
     transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
     transport.close();

  } catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

http://geronimo.apache.org/maven/javamail/geronimo-javamail_1.3.1_provider/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/geronimo/javamail/transport/smtp/SMTPTransport.html

Line 1827
if (useTLS) {

// if we've been told to use TLS, and this server doesn't support

// it, then this is a failure

if (!serverTLS) {

```
 throw new MessagingException("Server doesn't support required transport level security");
```

}